# Foreach loop performance searching a list

Tags: c#, performance, loops

I have a SQL table of document information, and a second table with security information on these documents.

There are over 2 million document rows, and over 6 million rows with security information.

I need to concatenate the security information and save it back to the document tables [Security] column.

It currently seems to be bottlenecking in the foreach loop, where each document searches the list of **securityLines** for it's collection of security policies.

Here is my current working code

```
public static Task ApplyDocumentSecurity()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int totalDocCount = 0;
        int take = 5000;
        using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities ())
        {
            // get total document count
            totalDocCount = db.MigrationMasters.Count();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < totalDocCount; i = i + take)
        {                
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
            {
                var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
                objectContext.CommandTimeout = 3600; // 1 hour

                // get the next 5,000 entries
                var documents = (from d in context.MigrationMasters
                          where d.Security == null
                          select new { d.ID, d.DocNum, d.Version }).Take(take).ToList();

                // get a list of the unique docnums
                var uniqueDocNums = documents.Select(x => x.DocNum).Distinct();

                // retrieve all the security policies for those documents                   
                var securityLines = new List<DocumentSecurity>();
                securityLines = context.DocumentSecurities
                                          .Where(s => uniqueDocNums.Contains(s.DocNum)).ToList();  

                // loop through each document and get the security policies from 
                // the short list now in memory             
                 List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

                    foreach (var document in documents)
                    {
                        var localCopyDoc = document;

                        // the below task may be running on another thread
                        var task = Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            var securityLinesMatch = (from s in securityLines
                                                      where s.DocNum == localCopyDoc.DocNum && s.Version == localCopyDoc.Version
                                                      select s).ToList();

                            // manipulate security lines and join them, then save.
                            string acl = JoinSecurityLines(securityLinesMatch);
                            using (MyEntities context2 = new MyEntities())
                            {
                                var docToUpdate = context2.MigrationMasters.Find(localCopyDoc.ID);
                                docToUpdate.Security = String.IsNullOrEmpty(acl) ? "<Default>" : acl;
                                context2.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        });
                        taskList.Add(task);
                    }                   
                    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
           }                 
       }
   });
}
```

**Benchmarks:**

Take 5,000 completes 20,000 documents in 0.84 minutes. And 200,000 was done in about 8 minutes. So I am looking at 80 minutes or so for this to complete.

Take 10,000 completed 20,000 documents in 0.88 minutes. So slightly slower, presumably because it had a larger list of securityLines to search through for each document.

Is there another approach to this that would be faster? I tried selecting the documents and joining on security in one LINQ query, and while it was much cleaner, it that ran far slower than what I have here.

Comment: Your code seems to only get the first 5000 records over and over. You never use `i` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Reading the entire file first and then accessing it will change the time complexity as io is slow and slows more when you do multiple compared to one large batch. Increase the timeout to stop the large batch from failing.  The bottleneck will be your hardware and not the application if you do this ( hardware is faster)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am only accessing records where security == null. In this situation every record will have at least one security policy, so every record should get updated. But your point is valid, in the future this might not always be the case. I originally considered a Skip(i).Take(5000) approach but it had issues translating the SQL for SQL Server 2008 (I'm developing on SQL 2012) - I definitely should focus on fixing that.

Comment: @shon When I increased the timeout further and attempted to do it in one large batch I got OutOfMemoryException. I didn't mention I am limited by the hardware in this scenario. I do think the cost of searching through a enormous list impacts performance more than additional database calls in this scenario, and my test where I increase the 'take' value to 10,000 verifies this (although I hear an argument for 0.04 minutes not being a considerable enough margin).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  EDIT to my original comment back to you - actually even if there is no security policy to apply it should update to "<Default>" (this is in my code), so it should never get the same record twice.